# listbox data binding fails silently

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This approach seems to work half the time for me.

I can see these lines get executed in the debugger:

```
agencyListBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", this.Data.Agencies, "AvailableAgencies"));
agencyListBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", this.Data.Agencies, "SelectedAgency", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The agencies class looks like this:

```
public AgencyType SelectedAgency
{
    get
    {
        return _selected;
    }
    set
    {
        _selected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAgency");
    }
}

public List<AgencyType> AvailableAgencies
{
    get
    {
        return _availableList;
    }
    set
    {
        _availableList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AvailableAgencies");
    }
}
```

So the fields I reference in the binding do exist.

The DisplayMember is set to "Label" which is defined in the AgencyType class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private string _label { get; set; }

public string Label
{
    get { return _label; }
    set
    {
        _label = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Label");
    }
}

private string _identifier { get; set; }

public string Identifier
{
    get { return _identifier; }
    set
    {
        _identifier = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Identifier");
    }
}

public AgencyType()
{
    Label = string.Empty;
    Identifier = string.Empty;
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The values are displayed as desired.

But then when I change the selection, data.Agencies.SelectedAgency is null!

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Why would you have a set on AvailableAgencies.  It is not like you can change a List in a UI?

Comment: @Blam: The List is a list of options in the ListBox. It's not changing between lists; it's changing between elements in the list. The same concept is working in other places in my UI.

Comment: If the list of options is not changing the why does it have a set.  Did you try removing the set on AvailableAgencies?

Comment: @Blam: It changes when I initially populate it (from somewhere else). The available agencies display as desired, but the selected agency always stays null. Seems like the easy part!